# UsageError: Line magic function `%tensorboard` not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I try to use tensorboard in jupyter lab but the use of the `%tensorboard --logdir logs/fit` line magic do not work.

- Jupyterlab: '0.33.12'
- ipython: '7.2.0'
- python: '3.6.7'
- tensorflow: '2.0.0-dev20190426'

I have this message when I try `%load_ext tensorboard`.

- The tensorboard module is not an IPython extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorboard not found as magic function in jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970686/tensorboard-not-found-as-magic-function-in-jupyter)

Comment: #%load_ext tensorboard.notebook \\n
%load_ext tensorboard in my case from explore a tf examples

Answer (score 2):

For older versions of Tensorflow 1 and Tensorflow 2, you want to load tensorboard notebook in ipython first:

> %load_ext tensorboard.notebook

Then run it like this:

> %tensorboard --logdir logs/scalars

Comment: @ClementWalter It is probably because you are using a newer version of TF1 or TF2 (tensorflow>=1.14.0 & tensorflow != 2.0.0a0) (newer than TF2-alpha)