# Tensorboard not found as magic function in jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tensorflow2.x

I want to run tensorboard in jupyter using the latest tensorflow 2.0.0a0. 
With the tensorboard version 1.13.1, and python 3.6.

using

`...
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}`

I get the error :

`UsageError: Line magic function %tensorboard not found`

Do you have an idea what the problem could be? It seems that all versions are up to date and the command seems correct too.

Thanks

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For newer TF versions (`tensorflow>=1.14.0` & `tensorflow != 2.0.0a0` -  newer than TF2.0-alpha) load the extension like this

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

**OLD ANSWER**

The extension needs to be loaded first:

```
%load_ext tensorboard.notebook
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
```

Comment: Dear Vlad, thanks. Stupid me, I thought that would only hold for the previous TensorFlow versions. Have a nice day

Answer (score 12):

If you are using TF 2.0 you can execute the code below from your notebook environment, prior to your magic command:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

Answer (score 6):

That's how I solved it

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir /content/drive/MyDrive/Dog\ Vision/logs
```

After `--logdir`, this is my path directory `/content/drive/MyDrive/Dog\ Vision/logs`. It should be different for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Year 2020**

I needed to pip uninstall both `tensorflow` and `tensorboard`

Then install `tf-nightly`

In order to get this to work

```
%load_ext tensorboard.notebook
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
```

Answer (score 0):

extension loading is required before. You can try -> `%load_ext tensorboard` 
.It worked for me. I am using TensorFlow 1.>